# Magento 2.3 GRAPHQL

Tags: magento2.3, graphql

How to run Api request in Magento's newly introduced feature **Graphql**. I have gone through some of the documents. In my local environemnt, So far I have installed **ChromeiQL** extension from chrome version 1.0.

The site is in **developer mode.**

In the search bar i have entered the

```
http:magento-root-url/graphql
```

After that i have tried to get the product by filtering price, so i have executed the following query for that,

```
{
  products (
    filter: {
      price: {
        gt: "1"
      }
    }
  ) 
  {
    items {
        name
    }
  }
}
```

But it throws following error,

**TypeError: Failed to fetch**.

Do I need to perform any other Configurations changes before the request is made.

Kindly help me with this..

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload your schema.graphqls file?

Comment: i didn't create schema.graphqls file .. Do we need to create ?

Comment: Yes. I think you need to create for price filter.

Comment: Strange ..!! I got output proper by your query which you mentioned in question.

Comment: Do we need to make any configuartion changes in admin panel?

Comment: could you explain in steps what you have done?

Comment: I just copy your query which you mentioned in question (Not screenshot query) and execute and output display proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96642/discussion-between-aravind-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your actual problem. But, it's working fine. Just follow this step :

```
{
  products (
    filter: {
      price: {
        gt: "40"
        lt: "50"
      }
    }
  ) 
  {
    items {
        name
    }
  }
}
```

Copy this above query at left side (In query variable part) and just  execute "**Execute-Query**" button **(Ctrl + Enter)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...still the same issue..Does this work in ubuntu ? I am using ubuntu

Comment: Yes. I'm also use ubuntu.

Comment: Then i don't know why the results are not coming..What is your version?

Comment: It's 1.0 ............

Comment: mine also 1.0..

Comment: Hello @rohan in your local ssl certificate enabled or disabled? and what is your php version ?

Comment: ssl not enabled. php version is 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you entered **http://** yourdomain.com/graphql

I got the error `TypeError: Failed to fetch.` because I put mydomain.com/graphql without **http://**

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try below sample request.

```
{
  products(
    filter: {
      sku: {
        like: "24-MB%"
      }
      price: {
        lt: "50"
      }
    }
  )
  {
    items {
      sku
   }
}
```

Comment: still same issue..Whatever command i execute it throws same error

Comment: your storefront working well ?

Comment: yes i can access the site in frontend ..Only graphql issue..Look at my attached image

Comment: ok. can you try after enabling developer mode ?

Comment: it is in developer mode only.. I performing in my local environment